# Logs eventsource failed

Tags: node.js, logging

I create a nodejs app.
`heroku local web` works perfect.
However when I pushed it to heroku and open the application, error message pops up

[ui error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNGVv.png)

When I tried `heroku logs --tail`, another error shows up on the console
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uVP1.png).

Please help me fix this, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in? In order to view your logs you have to be logged in to your account on Heroku.

Comment: Yes, I can use ```heroku open``` to open my app in the browser, and the url is correct

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this post and I figured out where the problem is by executing 
`heroku run bash` and manually restarting the program and soon observed the error in the output.

It was because I omitted installing one dependency, which caused the nodejs program fail to start.

However, the output of `heroku logs --tail` still needs improving. It does not return anything useful other than a 400 error.